# Ionic 3 - Entering a deep link renders the page before the app initializes

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

My app.component handles the authentication and renders the main-menu.component only when the user is authenticate. That used to work great, but now, since I upgraded to Ionic 3, it doesn't work when I enter a deep link, before Ionic creates the link's page before it creates the app.component

What's the best practice here?

I don't really need the deep links, can I disable them somehow? If not, what should I do?

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11067#issuecomment-291906808